# Eclipse JDBC MySQL Foreign Keys Syntax to incorporate multiple keys

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, foreign-keys

I am creating a Java program in Eclipse to create a database table with multiple foreign keys. However, I am getting a syntax error. I have tried switching things around with the foreign key syntax, but can't seem to get it right. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

## My Code:

```
String sql5 = "CREATE TABLE Writers" +
    "(tconst_writers VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Titles(tconst_titles), " +
    " writers VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(nconst_persons)) ";

myStmt1.executeUpdate(sql5);
```

Comment: According to [these examples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) you're using incorrect syntax. What you've used works with `SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access` but not in `MySQL`.

Comment: You were right. Thanks.